# Controller need not met

Tags: ember.js

I have the following routes setup:

```
this.resource('password_reset', { path: '/password_reset' }, function() {
    this.route("request");  // request a password reset
    this.route("sent");     // instruct user that email has been sent
    this.route("claim");    // receive nonce link from email to claim the reset
});
```

And when a user requests a reset they are asked to put in their username or email address to identify themselves:

[image: request]

When the user pressed the "request reset" button we are transitioned to the "password_reset.sent" route where the user is instructed about the email that has been sent.

[image]

As a convenience function they are given a button which can resend the email. In order for this to happen I need the `username` property from the controller for the `password_reset.request` route. I figured I'd use the 'need' property to get this working:

```
App.PasswordResetSentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs:'password_reset.request',
    usernameBinding: "controllers.password_reset.request.username",
    username: null,
```

Now I don't get any errors from this but it doesn't seem to work either. The debugger shows the state of the PasswordResetSentController to be:

[image: debug info]

There's a lot I don't understand here. Nearest and dearest to my heart is of course the `username` which remains in it's initialised state of *null*. Beyond that, why are all the properties in the two `App.PasswordResetSentController` grouping boxes crossed out? Also why are there two of these boxes both for `App.PasswordResetSentController`?

I looked at the "controllers" and "usernameBinding" properties with the hope that I'd find my way around in there but they didn't help me shed any light on it. For those who's ember flame burns a little brighter, here's the binding object:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with binding only.

Change your PasswordResetSentController as

```
App.PasswordResetSentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs:'password_reset.request',
    username: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.password_reset.request.username"),
});
```

There are issues in binding, and it's been advised to use Computed properties, in place of Binding, and it's discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1164#issuecomment-18691006)

Comment: Ok thanks. Good advice. I am now receiving this error though ... any idea what its really saying? `Uncaught ReferenceError: <App.PasswordResetSentController:ember720>#needs does not include 'password_reset'. To access the password_reset controller from <App.PasswordResetSentController:ember720>, <App.PasswordResetSentController:ember720> should have a 'needs' property that is an array of the controllers it has access to.`

Comment: If I change the computed reference to: `request: Ember.computed.alias("password_reset.request")` I don't get any error but the debugger states that the `request` property is null instead of being a pointer to the password_reset.request controller.

Comment: Try changing the needs as `password_resetRequest` and alias as `controllers.password_resetRequest.username`, and check if it works.

Comment: Wow. That worked. That's one ugly naming reference but if it works I guess I'll stop complaining.